# P-Uniform* interpretation

Tags: meta-analysis, publication-bias

I have a question concering the interpretation of my p-uniform* results.

So this is my results:

Estimating effect size p-uniform*

```
   est     ci.lb     ci.ub       L.0    pval
0.8742      0.43    1.3071   11.2626   <.001
```

===

Estimating between-study variance p-uniform*

```
  tau2   tau2.lb   tau2.ub     L.het    pval
0.2769     0.115    0.6656   41.1127   <.001
```

===

Publication bias test p-uniform*

```
  L.pb      pval
0.5127    0.7739
```

I just wanted to confirm that my interpretation is correct. Non-significance of the publication bias test indicates that there is no publication bias? Is that correct?

KR

Comment: What is a "p-uniform*" result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a side-note: A non-significant test doesn't indicate that the null hypothesis is true, it indicates that there is not sufficient evidence to reject the null hypothesis. This aside, yes, the test indicates that there is not sufficient evidence to conclude that publication bias is present.